# Drupal Json Output strange characters when pulling from other language

Tags: ajax, i18n-l10n

Hi Fellow drupal experts,

I have a problem, I developed a custom page intended to do a drupal json output :

and here is the code :

    `function blogpull_menu() {`

```
$items = array();

$items['blogpull'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'blogpull_view',
    'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
```

}

function blogpull_view() {
    global $base_url;
    global $language;
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'blog')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->propertyCondition('language', $language->language, '=') // filter by current language
      ->range(0, 5)
      ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.
    $result = $query->execute();
    if (isset($result['node'])) {
      $blog_items_nids = array_keys($result['node']);
      $blog_items = entity_load('node', $blog_items_nids);
    }

```
foreach ($blog_items as $key => $blog_item) {
    $arr = array('date' => date('M. j, Y', $blog_items[$key]->created), 'title' => $blog_items[$key]->title, 'description' => $blog_items[$key]->body['und'][0]['value'], 'href' => $base_url.'/node/'.$blog_items[$key]->nid);
    $arrs[] = $arr;
}

return $arrs;
```

}

and some how when it's loading the japanese language it is showing this strange characters :
ã‚¯ãƒ©ã‚¦ãƒ‰ã‚²ãƒ¼ãƒ äº‹æ¥­ã®æ–°ä¼šç¤¾ã€Œã‚·ãƒ³ãƒ©ãƒ»ãƒ†ã‚¯ãƒŽãƒ­ã‚¸ãƒ¼ã€ç™ºè¶³

I tied using utf-encoding, mb_encoding and so on but nothing happen

can someone help?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just check HTTP response headers it should have utf-8 charset.

Comment: the page just throw out nothing without the headers, I tried adding drupal_add_headers into it but still not working